# Building only required docker-compose.yaml services with VS Code Dev Container

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using VS Code Dev Container extension to develop and run my app inside a Docker container.

I'm using a `docker-compose.yaml` to re-use an already defined image with a dependent service.

Inside that `docker-compose.yaml` file I have yet another service for testing purposes. When VS Code starts it builds **all** of the services inside my `docker-compose.yaml` file, not just the two I need to develop my application.

I can see Dev Container extension runs the command `Start: Run: docker-compose --project-name proj1 -f c:\dev\proj1\docker-compose.yaml -f c:\dev\proj1\.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml up -d --build`

If it would have passed the service defined in `devcontainer.json` it would have built only it.

Is there a way to instruct VS Code's Dev Container extension to build only the service I need for my development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
"runServices": ["devcontainer-1", "devcontainer-2"],
```

to `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` will make vscode to only build and run listed services.